# Scalar multiplied by a vector

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

I was looking up the cross product, namely why crossing unit vectors gives negative and positive results depending on the order, when I stumbled upon this:

[image]

Am I going crazy, or is that not how vectors work. It should be:

$$\alpha  \vec r = \alpha (r \hat r + \theta \hat \theta)$$

Was this a typo or am I missing something?

Comment: You're correct. But their original equation for $\mathbf r$ is garbage. It's simply $\mathbf r = r\hat{\mathbf r}$.

Comment: I agree with that as well. That's troubling to see considering it was a top search result.

Comment: Moral of the story: There's a lot of garbage on the internet. Be very critical.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, do you know if there's a good proof I might find for the necessity of scaling component-wise with vectors? I'd like to know why this is wrong more than just saying it's not the way we do things.

Comment: It's just a definition ... You can motivate it by thinking about similar right triangles, not wanting to change the direction of the hypotenuse.

Comment: Right, since not scaling all the components of the triangle will change the orientation (and length I'd image) of the hypotenuse?

Comment: Right. Well, we're changing length anyhow, of course. But it is just definition. Ultimately it makes sense in vector spaces where you can't write down "components" (like the vector space of continuous functions).

Comment: BTW, you might find some of my lectures from my integrated linear algebra/multivariable math (more proofs) course helpful. See the link in my profile.

Comment: These look really nice! Cheers!